# Using for statement to compare plots in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I am trying to compare and plot a variable's distribution with that of the variable's log transformation.

What I am saying below, for every variable in mtcars if it is either a numeric or an integer return a histogram of it, then return a histogram with a log transformation, so that I can compare.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
for(i in ncol(mtcars)){
   par(mfcol = c(1,2))
   if (as.numeric | as.integer(mtcars[,i]) == T){
      return(hist(mtcars[,i]))}
   if (as.numeric | as.integer(mtcars[,i]) == T){
      return(hist(log(mtcars[,i])+1))}
}

Error in as.numeric | as.integer(mtcars[, i]) == T : 
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Comment: You are not passing any argument to `as.numeric` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `hist()`, it's the `if` statement that does not make much sense.

- You want to use `is.numeric()` and `is.integer()`
- Both require the argument `is.numeric(mtcars[,i])` and
  `is.integer(mtcars[,i])`.
- `is.numeric()` and `is.integer()` already return a `boolean`, so there is no need to check `== T`

Your code should read:

```
for(i in ncol(mtcars)){
  if (is.numeric(mtcars[,i]) | is.integer(mtcars[,i])){
    return(hist(mtcars[,i]))
    return(hist(log(mtcars[,i])+1)}
}
```

You should also know that it's almost always better to leverage the `apply` functions family instead of loops, e.g.:

```
apply(mtcars, 2, function(x) {hist(log(x)+1); hist(x)})
```

Comment: Thank you GGamba. I will use this function to tackle similar requests.

Comment: the only thing that is missing when using the applying statement are the names of the histograms. So its sort of rough to compare and contrast transformed variables versus their original forms.

Comment: That's true, we modify and use: `sapply(names(mtcars), function(x) {hist(log(mtcars[,x])+1, xlab = x); hist(mtcars[,x], xlab = x)})`. Note the use of `sapply` instead of `apply`

Answer (score 1):

You should use function `is.numeric` and `is.integer`. Using `as.` makes no sense in an if statement.

This would be the correct approach:

```
for(i in ncol(mtcars)){
    par(mfcol = c(1,2))
    if (is.numeric(mtcars[,i] | is.integer(mtcars[,i])){
       return(hist(mtcars[,i]))
    }
    else {
       return(hist(log(mtcars[,i])+1))
    }
}
```